# Windows Threading Wait Method

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm creating a thread class to encapsulate the windows thread methods. I'm trying to create a method that makes the application wait for the thread to complete before it exits the application. If I use a while loop and boolean flag, it works but obviously it spikes my CPU use and it's just not ideal.

What ways would you use to wait for the completion of a thread? I'm not really looking for code here, just areas to look into.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

After you use CreateThread to get a thread handle, pass it into the Win32 API [WaitForSingleObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687032.aspx):

```
WaitForSingleObject(threadhandle, INFINITE);
```

If you do not use CreateThread (because you use another threading package), or perhaps your thread is always alive...

Then you can still use WaitForSingleObject.  Just create an event first with the Win32 API [CreateEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682396(VS.85).aspx), and wait for the event to be set with WaitForSingleObject.  At the end of your thread set the event with [SetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686211(VS.85).aspx) and you can reset the event with [ResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685081(VS.85).aspx).

Most threading packages though will have their own way to wait for a thread.   Like in [boost::thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/thread.html) you can use .join() or a [boost::condition.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_0/doc/html/boost/condition.html)

Comment: Only problem is I am wanting to re-use this thread, so when the unit of work (a functor) has completed the thread is suspended, so WaitForSingleObject runs indefinately

Comment: Ok, then you can use the event method I mentioned instead.

Comment: While it will probably be "harmless" in the stated case, in general, suspending the thread is not a clean approach. Make threads block when no tasks are to be done, never suspend them. Suspend is evil. Also, let threads exit, not die. At program end, send the worker a "exit" task, and then wait on its handle. Having threads exit cleanly (rather than being killed off when the process dies) is the only formally correct way of ensuring no data is corrupted. Mind you, a thread dying unexpectedly might among other things abort writes to files before they complete.

Comment: I tested this, and after the wait I can still break in the thread (it's still running). This answer is probably incomplete.