# C winsock and _beginthreadex compile error

Tags: c

I have an ugly C code (I'm newbie in C under Windows) don't judge me...I wat to make it multithreading, it reads from a list of my webservers and check if them are alive, for fastness I need it to be multithreaded. Searched a lot of google and howtos and the best I could do is as follows:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <winsock.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <string.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "wsock32.lib")

int isAlive(char *addr)
{
  struct sockaddr_in blah;
  struct hostent *he;
  WSADATA wsaData;
  int i;
  WORD wVersionRequested;
  SOCKET sock;

  char buff[1024];
  char *ex;
  ex="GET /alive.php HTTP/1.0\n\n";
  char *fmsg="ALIVE";  

  wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(1, 1);
  if (WSAStartup(wVersionRequested , &wsaData)){
    printf("Winsock Initialization failed.\n");
    return(1);
  }

  if ((sock=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0))==INVALID_SOCKET){
    printf("Can not create socket.\n");
    return(1);
  }
  sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
  blah.sin_family = AF_INET;
  blah.sin_port = htons(80);
  blah.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(addr);

  if ((he=gethostbyname(addr))!=NULL){
    memcpy((char *)&blah.sin_addr.s_addr,he->h_addr,he->h_length);
  }
  else{
    if((blah.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(addr))==-1){
      WSACleanup();
      return(1);
    }
  }

  if (connect(sock,(struct sockaddr*)&blah,sizeof(blah))==0){
    send(sock,ex,strlen(ex),0);
    recv(sock,buff,sizeof(buff),0);
    if(strstr(buff,fmsg)!=NULL){
      printf("ALIVE: %s", addr);
    }
  }

  closesocket(sock);
  WSACleanup();
  _endthreadex(0);
  return(1);
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
  if(argc!=2){
    printf("Usage: scan <webservers list>\n");
    return(1);
  }

  char *inname = argv[1];
  FILE *infile;
  char line_buffer[BUFSIZ];
  char line_number;
  int numconnect;

  infile = fopen(inname, "r");
  if (!infile) {
    printf("Couldn't open file %s for reading.\n", inname);
    return 0;
  }

  line_number = 0;
  numconnect=20;
  while (fgets(line_buffer, sizeof(line_buffer), infile)) {
    ++line_number;
    //printf("%s", line_buffer);
    unsigned x;
    unsigned tempThreadID;
    for(x=0;x<numconnect;++x){
        _beginthreadex(0, 0, isAlive, line_buffer, 0, &tempThreadID);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile under VC 10 I get the following error:

> checkalive.c(90) : error C2664: '*beginthreadex' : cannot convert
>   parameter 3 from 'int (*_cdecl *)(char *)' to 'unsigned int (__stdcall
>   *)(void *)'

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the MSDN docs for [beginthreadex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).  You need to change the signature of `isAlive` to

```
unsigned int _stdcall isAlive(void *ptr)
```

`_stdcall` specifies a different calling convention.  See [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/100832) for a list of the available options.

You can retrieve your `addr` argument simply by casting `ptr`:

```
char* addr = (char*)ptr;
```

Comment: Yes! Very right! Now my code compiles OK, the only problem I think it's doing nothing :-|

Comment: I think I don't get anything back from my threads to the main thread.

Comment: Your program will exit after starting its threads.  You can join the child threads to wait on them completing.

Comment: How can I achieve that? Joining the child threads and wait for them to complete. WaitForSingleObject()?

Comment: [This previous SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/811641/windows-threading-wait-method) covers waiting for a thread to exit

Comment: Yes, is what I did, reading MSDN docs for beginthreadex, but that covers one thread not multiple threads. Anyway, I'll figure it out, thanks!

Comment: If you only want to know that all threads have exited, store their handles in an array then loop through the array waiting on each handle in turn.  Your waiting loop will only complete when the final thread exits