# Joining and terminating a windows thread

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi, handle

I am trying to create a thread using windows threads as following:

```
HANDLE hUSBPollThread = CreateThread(
            NULL,
            NULL,
            USBCan::CreateUSBPollLoop,
            (LPVOID) this,
            0,
            &outThreadID);
```

However I could not find any functions to Join or Terminate the thread from outside of the thread. Could anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: This looks promising: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/811641/windows-threading-wait-method

Comment: 1. Simple Join = `WaitForSingleObject(hUSBPollThread,INFINITE);` 2. **Never** invoke `TerminateThread()` unless you are doing so as part of an emergency shutdown sequence (and even then, take every possible human endeavor to avoid having to do it).

Answer (score 2):

If you terminate the thread externally, how can you be sure that no resources are leaked, no synchronization objects are left locked? Yes you can kill thread with [`TerminateThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686717%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but you should not be doing it.

What you do instead is: you signal an internal event that you want to terminate thread operation, and thread proc will eventually notice this request and return/exit closing thread activity.

Comment: so how would you signal it? What im actually trying to do in my Uninitialize function is: Set bool threadRunning to false and wait for couple of seconds for thread to exit. If it doesnt then I want to force it to shut down.

Comment: The first comment above has a link which explains signaling with `SetEvent`.

Comment: In regards to `"If it doesn't then I want to force it to shut down."` Rather than doing the wrong thing, test to see if that condition ever happens. If you code it right, it won't happen. TerminateThread is evil.

Comment: @MiroBucko: You answered your own question. "how would you signal it?" "set bool threadRunning to false". That is a simple kind of signal. `CreateUSBPollLoop()` would periodically check `threadRunning` and exit if it is false. After setting `threadRunning` to false, use `WaitForSingleObject()` to wait for the thread to terminate itself up to a specified amount of time. If it times out, then you can use `TerminateThread()` (but that is not advisable unless you have no other choice).